# How to rotate image placed on a Mapcontrol

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml, uwp-maps

## The issue

I've got an application that tracks vehicles on a map. However I cannot get the little buggers to rotate in the direction of their motion. Basically, all of them are going sideways! Ugh!

[image: Little icons of cars on a map]

## The code

```
Image vehicleImage = new Image
{
  //Set image size and source
};
RenderTransform rotation= new RotateTransform{Angle = X};
vehicleImage.RenderTransfrom = rotation; 
_mainMap.Children.Add(vehicleImage);
MapControl.SetLocation(vehicleImage, _position);
```

The Image, placed on the map, seems to completely ignore any angle I try to apply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To understand why the rotation doesn't take effect, let's first take a look at the image below, which is taken from the *Live Visual Tree* in Visual Studio -

[image]

I use a `Rectangle` but in your case, you will see your `Image` control there instead. When you insert it into the `MapControl.Children` collection, it will be wrapped with a special element called `MapOverlayPresenter` (as shown in the picture).

This `MapOverlayPresenter` is an internal element within `MapControl` and surprisingly, there's no official documentation on the Internet on what exactly it does. My guess is, as you zoom or rotate the map, this overlay simply responds by zooming or rotating in the opposite direction in order to maintain the original size and rotation of the child element, and this is causing the rotation transform of your inner `Image` to somehow get lost.

*(P.S. [`RotationAngle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.visual#Windows_UI_Composition_Visual_RotationAngle) and [`RotationAngleInDegrees`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.visual#Windows_UI_Composition_Visual_RotationAngleInDegrees) from Composition have no effect here either.)*

---

### Solution

The way to work around this is simple - instead of exposing the rotation transform on the `Image` directly, create a `UserControl` called `ImageControl` which encapsulates this `Image` and its transform, with dependency properties like `UriPath` and `Angle` that are responsible for passing the information down to the inner `Image` and its `CompositeTransform` property.

**The `ImageControl` XAML**

```
<UserControl x:Class="App1.ImageControl" ...>
    <Image RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
           Source="{x:Bind ConvertToBitmapImage(UriPath), Mode=OneWay}"
           Stretch="UniformToFill">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform Rotation="{x:Bind Angle, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
</UserControl>
```

**The `ImageControl` code-behind**

```
public string UriPath
{
    get => (string)GetValue(UriPathProperty);
    set => SetValue(UriPathProperty, value);
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty UriPathProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "UriPath", typeof(string), typeof(ImageControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));     

public double Angle
{
    get => (double)GetValue(AngleProperty);
    set => SetValue(AngleProperty, value);
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty AngleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Angle", typeof(double), typeof(ImageControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(double)));

public BitmapImage ConvertToBitmapImage(string path) => new BitmapImage(new Uri(BaseUri, path));
```

**How to use this `ImageControl`**

```
var vehicleImage = new ImageControl
{
    Width = 80,
    UriPath = "/Assets/car.png",
    Angle = 45
};

_mainMap.Children.Add(vehicleImage);
```

**Outcome**

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome, detailed answer! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why it shows an error -  "ConvertToBitmapImage" was not found in type ImageControl ?

Comment: @user2431727 you need to target 14393 or later to use function x:Bind.

Comment: my target is 10240. Can I pass a bitmapimage directly from vehicleImage? instead of uriPath ?

Comment: @user2431727 you just need to write a normal value converter instead.

Comment: I have done like below.but nothing happens.BitmapImage CarIconSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/car.png")); var vehicleImage = new ImageControl
                    {
                        Width = 80,
                      UriPath= CarIconSource,
                        Angle = 90
                    }; And datatype of UriPath in ImageControl codebehind changed to BitMapImage. Then this UriPath is passed to Source="{x:Bind UriPath, Mode=OneWay}"

Comment: @JustinXL  I have opened a new thread in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51557070/call-a-function-from-usercontrol-uwp-c-sharp?noredirect=1#comment90084298_51557070